# Regex in a resource-file

Tags: c#, regex, windows-runtime

I need to save a regular expression in a resource-file, and it should be possible to e.g. replace the first character in a string, replace a specific string and something like that

Is it possible to do that?

How should a regular-expression e.g. look like to replace the first character?

Comment: [www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace first char:

```
string res = Regex.Replace("text", "^.", "replacement");
```

replace last char:

```
string res = Regex.Replace("text", ".$", "replacement");
```

Comment: Is it also possible to use this inside a string, if the demand is changed?

Comment: @The87Boy what do u mean with "inside a string"? Give an example

Comment: If the string is e.g. <EXAMPLE><Query>...</Query></EXAMPLE> and the Query-string is changed to QUERY

Comment: It will always replace the first character of every string with "replacement" or whatever you write instead of replacement.

Comment: Yes, but If i change it to `...Replace("<EXAMPLE><Query>...</Query></EXAMPLE>"), "Query", "QUERY")` can it then be changed to only take the first and last?

Comment: @The87Boy in your example you will replace all occurrences of "Query" with "QUERY"

Comment: Yes, but could it be changed to only replace the first and the last one?

Comment: I am sorry, I mean't if this `...Replace("<EXAMPLE><Query>...</Query></EXAMPLE>"), "Query", "QUERY")` is possible to be changed, so it only replaces the first and last occurence of "Query"

Comment: yes, two patterns, replace first "^<EXAMPLE><Query>" and replace last "</Query></EXAMPLE>$"

Comment: But it is not possible to do in one?